# How to plot multiple dataframe columns with options for marker, color, and lw

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

While the line plot comes out fine, I am looking for a more efficient way to write this code and to shorten it. What would be considered 'best practices? New fella working on the foundations. I feel like I should be using a loop to go through assigning all the y values, and perhaps the plotting as well.

Data description:
Time series data 1990-2018, with continent electricity consumption (TWH).

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9)) 

plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Calibri'
plt.rcParams['axes.edgecolor']='#333F4B'
plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth']=0.8


X1 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,0]

y1 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,1]
y2 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,2]
y3 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,3]
y4 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,4]
y5 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,5]
y6 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,6]
y7 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,7]
y8 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,8]
y9 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,9]
y10 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,10]

ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)

plt.plot( X1, y2, marker='', color='#89FAB4', linewidth=3, label="OECD")
plt.plot( X1, y3, marker='', color='#FAE4A0', linewidth=2, label="BRICS")
plt.plot( X1, y4, marker='+', color='#FA837D', linewidth=1, label="Europe")
plt.plot( X1, y5, marker='o', color='#B049E3', linewidth=2, label="North America")
plt.plot( X1, y6, marker='', color='#E3BA5F', linewidth=2, label="Latin America")
plt.plot( X1, y7, marker='', color='#E35E54', linewidth=2, linestyle='dashed' , label="Asia") 
plt.plot( X1, y8, marker='', color='#6591EA', linewidth=1, label="Pacific")
plt.plot( X1, y9, marker='', color='#EB83C6', linewidth=1, label="Africa")
plt.plot( X1, y9, marker='', color='#EB1551', linewidth=1, label="Middle East")
plt.plot( X1, y10, marker='', color='#1802F4', linewidth=1, label="CIS")

plt.legend()
fig.tight_layout(pad=3)
fig.suptitle('Power Generated by Renewable Energy sources (TWh)', fontsize=22, y=1.02, color='#A2BDF2')
```

df

```
Year,World,OECD,BRICS,Europe,North America,Latin America,Asia,Pacific,Africa,Middle-East,CIS
1990,101855.54000000001,52602.490000000005,26621.070000000003,20654.88,24667.230000000003,5373.06,24574.190000000002,1197.89,4407.77,2581.86,16049.400000000001
1991,102483.56000000001,53207.25,26434.99,20631.620000000003,24841.68,5500.990000000001,24783.530000000002,1186.26,4535.700000000001,2744.6800000000003,15898.210000000001
1992,102588.23000000001,53788.75,25993.050000000003,20189.68,25341.77,5628.92,25690.670000000002,1209.52,4582.22,3081.9500000000003,14339.79
1993,103646.56000000001,54614.48,26283.800000000003,20189.68,25830.230000000003,5675.4400000000005,26876.93,1267.67,4721.780000000001,3349.44,13246.570000000002
1994,104449.03000000001,55579.770000000004,25993.050000000003,20085.010000000002,26365.210000000003,5989.450000000001,28098.08,1279.3000000000002,4803.1900000000005,3640.19,11606.740000000002
1995,107112.3,56754.4,26946.710000000003,20713.030000000002,26714.11,6024.34,29761.170000000002,1290.93,5000.900000000001,3744.86,11188.060000000001
1996,109763.94,58417.490000000005,27481.690000000002,21445.72,27295.61,6303.46,30772.980000000003,1372.3400000000001,5152.09,3814.6400000000003,10850.79
1997,110903.68000000001,59022.25000000001,27446.800000000003,21341.050000000003,27574.730000000003,6570.950000000001,31435.890000000003,1407.23,5280.02,4058.8700000000003,10373.960000000001
1998,111450.29000000001,59219.96000000001,27528.210000000003,21503.870000000003,27772.440000000002,6803.55,31331.22,1442.1200000000001,5431.21,4082.13,10152.99
1999,113974.0,60301.55,28319.050000000003,21306.16,28528.390000000003,6989.63,32412.81,1477.01,5559.14,4244.95,10373.960000000001
2000,116590.75,61685.520000000004,28923.81,21538.760000000002,29342.49,7024.52,33564.18,1500.27,5617.29,4314.7300000000005,10501.890000000001
2001,117521.15000000001,61452.920000000006,29528.570000000003,21934.18,28795.88,7036.150000000001,34227.090000000004,1477.01,5756.85,4663.63,10571.67
2002,120207.68000000001,61987.9,30552.010000000002,21969.07,29156.410000000003,7280.38,35680.840000000004,1523.5300000000002,5849.89,4884.6,10653.08
2003,124464.26000000001,62871.780000000006,33157.130000000005,22515.68,29377.38,7501.35,38181.29,1535.16,6140.64,4954.38,11036.87
2004,129953.62000000001,64058.04,35994.850000000006,22748.280000000002,29993.77,7780.47,41437.69,1558.42,6466.280000000001,5245.13,11188.060000000001
2005,133582.18000000002,64453.46000000001,38169.66,22864.58,30168.22,8059.59,43693.91,1570.0500000000002,6652.360000000001,5675.4400000000005,11222.95
2006,137396.82,64616.280000000006,40670.11,23108.81,29958.88,8303.82,46124.58,1616.5700000000002,6861.700000000001,5989.450000000001,11548.59
2007,141211.46000000002,64883.770000000004,43112.41,22829.690000000002,30424.08,8571.310000000001,48555.25,1663.0900000000001,7129.1900000000005,6315.09,11664.890000000001
2008,142874.55000000002,64034.780000000006,44635.94,22829.690000000002,29644.870000000003,8780.650000000001,49636.840000000004,1721.24,7443.200000000001,6850.070000000001,11874.230000000001
2009,141490.58000000002,61197.060000000005,46426.96000000001,21608.54,28214.38,8559.68,51858.170000000006,1721.24,7606.02,7059.410000000001,10967.09
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Plot directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

  - This allows for multiple `color`, but not multiple `marker`, or `linewidth`, however, `style` will accept a list with a combination of marker, linestyle, and color. See the **Notes** section of [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) for the available `fmt` options for `style`.
- Using the data from the OP, in a dataframe (`df`).
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

```py
colors = ['#89FAB4', '#FAE4A0', '#FA837D', '#B049E3', '#E3BA5F', '#E35E54', '#6591EA', '#EB83C6', '#EB1551', '#1802F4']
styles = ['', '', '-+', '-o', '', '', '', '', '', '']

ax = df.plot(x='Year', y=df.columns[2:], style=styles, color=colors, figsize=(16, 9))  # plot the dataframe and set Time as x
fig = ax.get_figure()  # extract the figure object
ax.set_xticks(df.Year)  # set the xticks
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.01), loc='upper left') # move the legend
fig.tight_layout(pad=3)
fig.suptitle('Power Generated by Renewable Energy sources (TWh)', fontsize=22, y=1.02, color='#A2BDF2')
```

[image]

---

- Alternatively, combine the values for each plot using `zip`, and iterate through each combination of values.

```py
markers = ['', '', '+', 'o', '', '', '', '', '', '']
colors = ['#89FAB4', '#FAE4A0', '#FA837D', '#B049E3', '#E3BA5F', '#E35E54', '#6591EA', '#EB83C6', '#EB1551', '#1802F4']
lws = [3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
columns = df.columns[2:]  # select all the columns except Year and World

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9)) 
for marker, color, lw, col in zip(markers, colors, lws, columns):
    df.plot(x='Year', y=col, marker=marker, color=color, lw=lw, label=col, ax=ax)
    
ax.set_xticks(df.Year)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.01), loc='upper left')
fig.tight_layout(pad=3)
fig.suptitle('Power Generated by Renewable Energy sources (TWh)', fontsize=22, y=1.02, color='#A2BDF2')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just one follow up - would there be a particular situation that would lean you to choose one or the other? Which may be best for a certain context? Best practice? Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.J It's customary to use whichever implementation allows you to achieve the desired plot with the least amount of code. If there are many custom parameters like markers, colors, and line widths, then the second option. The first option is more succinct, but less flexible. pandas.DataFrame.plot and seaborn both use matplotlib. Getting the desired plot is often about shaping the dataframe. Plotting directly with pandas is usually easier with for a wide dataframe, while seaborn is better for a long dataframe.

Comment: Ugh! Wondering why the DV, since it's correctly implemented, explained, and the accepted answer. Seems like a DV is a bit unethical, and flies in the face of the DV reason, which is _This answer isn't useful_.

Comment: Hello @Mr.J, the comment was directed at whoever DVed the answer. Best Regards.

Answer (score -1):

You can minimalize implementation of that variables:

```
y1 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,1]
y2 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,2]
y3 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,3]
y4 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,4]
y5 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,5]
y6 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,6]
y7 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,7]
y8 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,8]
y9 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,9]
y10 = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,10]
```

You can crate a matrix with y's data:

```
y_data=[]
for y in range(1,11):  #number of ur variables +1 
 y_data.append = df_cont_cons.iloc[:,i]
```

now u can use that matrix to induce ur data, i show example of first two rows :

```
plt.plot( X1, y_data[0], marker='', color='#89FAB4', linewidth=3, label="OECD")
plt.plot( X1, y_data[1], marker='', color='#FAE4A0', linewidth=2, label="BRICS")
```

Comment: ofc we could list colors , linewidth, linestyle and labels , and loop everything together, i just concentrate at  y values