# How to show different colors on a plot for values from different columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

Please consider the small dataframe test:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             [1, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
             [1, 0.75, 0.25, 0.0],
             [1, 0.576, 0.396, 0.028]
         ],
         columns = ["State", "1", "2", "3"]
    )
```

I am now plotting the 3 last columns by:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot()

ax.plot(df[["1","2","3"]], label = ["1 (from 1)","2 (from 1)","3 (from 1)"], 
        color = "red", marker = ".", linestyle="-")
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),
          fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.show()
```

What would be the easiest way to show a different color for each column of data, such as "red" for column 1, "blue" for column 2 and green for column 3 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69410566/15521392 have a look here. This answer offers two options on how you could do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the easiest way would be to use the [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) *built-in* [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

Otherwise, you need to loop :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]
labels = ["1 (from 1)","2 (from 1)","3 (from 1)"]

for idx, col in enumerate(["1", "2", "3"]):
    ax.plot(df[col], label=labels[idx], color=colors[idx], marker=".", linestyle="-")

ax.legend(loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),
          fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **.plot.line()**:

```
df1 = df[["1","2","3"]]
axes = df1.plot.line(subplots=False, color={"1": "red", "2": "blue", "3":"green"})
```

or **.plot(style={})**

```
axes = df1.plot(style={"1": "*:r", "2": "-.b", "3":"+--g"})
```